# Get image from ip camera with url login in PHP

Tags: php, curl, web, ip, webcam

I need help to get img or html code from my ip camera with php, i see other posts with cgi webcams. But my ip camera use this formart for the login:

http://user:password@IP:port/Streaming/channels/1/picture

I use this code and work with other urls but no with my ip cam

```
<?php
    $html = file_get_contents('http://user:password@IP:port/Streaming/channels/1/picture');
    echo $html;
?>
```

It does not give an error but does not return anything.

Greetings and thank you

Comment: Try using `curl -v http://user:password@IP:port/Streaming/channels/1/picture` from the command line to see what data the camera is actually returning.

Comment: *   Trying xx.xx6.x63.1xx...
* Connected to XX (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 8887 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> GET /Streaming/channels/1/picture HTTP/1.1
> Host: XXXXXXX
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46U2VjdXIxOTQ=
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: image/jpeg; charset="UTF-8"
< Content-Length:113674
<

Comment: Oops, you just posted your password, you'll want to change that.

Comment: And really, pick a better password. :)

Comment: It looks like the cam is giving you a raw JPEG file. Your variable probably contains the image data but you can't just echo it and expect to see an image. If you do `echo strlen($html);` you should get the same number as in the `Content-Length` header.

Comment: Note the output is not HTML, so it might be easier to understand if you name it something like `$raw_jpeg_data` instead.

Comment: Return 0 :/. And yes later i will set new password XD

Comment: In that case, I'd use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead of `file_get_contents()` because that gives you access to the `curl_getinfo()` function, which is super handy for debugging.

Comment: array(26) { ["url"]=> string(82) "URL" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(0) ["header_size"]=> int(0) ["request_size"]=> int(0) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0.241004) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.040662) ["connect_time"]=> float(0) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["size_upload"]=> float(0) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(0) ["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) ["upload_content_length"]=>

Comment: float(-1) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" ["primary_ip"]=> string(0) "" ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } ["primary_port"]=> int(0) ["local_ip"]=> string(0) "" ["local_port"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Getting http_code = 0 indicates that the request itself failed. (I.e., not that the request succeeded and returned an error response.) Like what you'd see if there was no server listening on that IP/port or if you couldn't route to it. Is the machine with PHP the same machine that you did the command line curl from?

Comment: No, I did the test from my linux. My hosting is shared, I do not have access to the command line. But I used curl at other times and it worked perfectly. The weird thing is that it only happens to me from PHP, if I load the url with the credentials in my browser it works

Comment: I'll wager you're using GoDaddy.

Comment: No, Banahosting

Comment: They probably block nonstandard outbound ports. I'm assuming your camera's IP is public. Is it?

Comment: Yes its a public ip webcam

Comment: If you can change the port that the cam listens on to 80, I'd try that.

Comment: I LOVE U!!!!! Yess!!!! i contact with banahosting support and open the port for me and work fine!! Thank you very much I had been with this problem a lot of days

Comment: Woohoo, glad you got it working.

Comment: Now i cant display the img i use this code: $url =X';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
header ('content-type: image/jpeg');
readfile($result); . And connect fine but dont display the img the info say: ["content_type"]=> string(27) "image/jpeg; charset="UTF-8"

Comment: `readfile()` expects to be passed a filename, your variable `$result` contains a raw byte stream. Just echo it.